# What's the most canonical method for accessing a json api and storing it into a dict in python?

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests

Is the following good enough or is there a more canonical method?

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get(json_rest_url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

# work with data
```

Comment: If the content type is correctly returned as json... then you use `response.json()` instead... and you'd want `json.loads` (notice the `s` for string) instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `python-requests` you can use use `request.json()` as Jon Clements mentioned. This is when the response is in `json` format. `request.json()` will return a `dict` for you.

```
>>> import requests
>>> repos = requests.get("https://api.github.com/users/gamesbrainiac/repos").json()
>>> repos[0]['git_url']
'git://github.com/gamesbrainiac/DefinitelyTyped.git'
>>> repos[1]['git_url']
'git://github.com/gamesbrainiac/django-crispy-forms.git'
>>> repos[2]['git_url']
'git://github.com/gamesbrainiac/dots.git'
```

The above example uses the [github api](http://developer.github.com/). The `json` response is converted into a list of dicts. The docs correspond to the information regarding each of the repository projects on github.

You can visit the actual url that I used above to see the `json` data.